# Ascertaining that a BGA's decoupling capacitance is good enough

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, bga, verification

BGA parts often have a large number of power pins in the middle of the package.  It is of course important to ensure that the power rail has been sufficiently capacitively decoupled.  How can one go about actually verifying that the decoupling is sufficient given a hardware prototype?  Are there any measurements that one can do?

If it were a package with externally accessible power pins (e.g. a QFP) then one could probe those pins.  One obviously can't get to the pins under the BGA.

Answer (score 1):

Yee...kind of..

1. Get/compare reference design if available
2. Hook up (one-by-one) power lines to the scope and load up the chip to the fullest/highest freq for hours (use ceramic container and have fire extinguisher :D). I mean that's an old school I guess but its cool and always works (to me at least, I do 5MHz...10GHz BGA designs). Yeah, I burn them chips. But that's even better, before the production, isn't it?

I usually connect one scope channel to highest freq clk/data and another one to power lines.

Example below (green ch - fast changing signal, yellow ch - one of the power rails), you can see approx 450mV drops with bad decoupling.
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to get more about how to determine whether the decoupling was sufficient even on the inaccessible pins.

Comment: @RobGilton, one way is to probe on the decoupling capacitors rather than on the BGA pads. Another is run the chip (maybe over-clocked, depending on the type of chip) and see if there are any errors. Another is remove half of the capacitors and run it full tilt and see if there are any errors. This could involve multiple days of testing to check all important corner cases 1000's of times or more for errors.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks -- would you post those things as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> If it were a package with externally accessible power pins (e.g. a QFP) then one could probe those pins. One obviously can't get to the pins under the BGA.

It's not necessary to probe directly on the BGA pads. Anywhere that those nets are routed to is okay. For example, on the pads of the decoupling capacitors.

Of course you should also be sure to use good probing technique, use the shortest ground connection possible from the probe to the board, etc.

You could also consider focusing on the effect of the power supply noise rather than trying to measure the noise directly. For example, run the system for a long time, possibly at elevated temperature, and verify there are no data errors. To ensure there is margin, you could even remove some (half?) of the decoupling capacitors before doing this test.